# computing mean and standard deviation

Tags: java

creating a program that enables the user to enter an integer N, then reads N double values, and prints their mean (average value) and sample standard deviation (square root of the sum of the squares of their differences from the average, divided by N - 1).
So far I have this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AVGDevi

{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



    double x;

    double sum = 0;

    double average = 0;

    double dev = 0;

    double var = 0;

    double sqrx = 0;

    int n = 0;

    do 
    { 
        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        x = input.nextInt(); 
        if (x == -1)
        {
            break;
        }

        sum += x;
        n++;
        average = sum / n;      
        sqrx += Math.pow(x-average,2);
        var = sqrx / (n-1);
        dev = Math.sqrt(var);


    } while (x<= 0);

    System.out.println("Average: " + average);
    System.out.println("Deviation: " + dev);
  }

}
```

test case:

```
5
1
2
3
4
5
```

Currently getting this output

```
Enter an integer:
Average: 5.0
Deviation: NaN
```

Output should be

```
Enter an integer: Enter a number: Enter a number: Enter a number: Enter a number: Enter a number: Average value is: 3.0
The standard deviation is: 1.58
```

I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong any help would be great :D !

Comment: Do your calculations **after** the loop ends. You're dividing by 0 otherwise. Also you will want to look up int division and then avoid doing it.

Comment: so after the if statement ?

Comment: I was trying to make it that if its a negative number it doesnt count it or something

Comment: An if statement is not a loop. Think -- what loop are you using, and where does it end? What good does it do to make the calculations before the user has entered all numbers?

Comment: thanks for the advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only while loop instead of do-while loop, as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);




double y=-1;

double sum = 0;

double average = 0;

double dev = 0;

double var = 0;

double sqrx = 0;

int n = 0;


    System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
    y = input.nextInt();
    double z=y;
    int i=0;
    double x[] = new double[(int)z];
    while(y-->0){

   x[i] = input.nextDouble();

    sum += x[i];
   i++;         
    n++;
    average = sum / n;      


    }
    i=0;
    while(z-->0){
        sqrx += Math.pow(x[i]-average,2);
        i++;
    }
 var = sqrx / (n-1);
    dev = Math.sqrt(var);

System.out.println("Average: " + average);
System.out.println("Deviation: " + dev);
  }
```

Comment: I get this error when i try it with some more test cases Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  I tried these test cases 3
1.5
2
2.5

Comment: it was because , for scanning double, you were using `input.nextInt()` instead of `input.nextDouble()`.

Comment: I'm still getting java.util.InputMismatchException would i have to bring up an exception ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `x <= 0` in the do-while guard, so if you enter a positive number, it will exit after the first iteration. Also, when you enter the first number, you will have `var = sqrx / (n-1)`, but for `n=1`, you are dividing by 0. As Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested, I'd add the numbers into a vector or ArrayList and do the calculation after you receive all input.